# Проверка общей коллекции в многопоточном приложении

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть коллекция, в которой лежат объекты класса "Магазин". У каждого объекта "Магазин" есть числовое поле "Количество товаров".
Потоки перемещают товары из одного магазина в другой. Я хочу создать один поток, который будет следить за тем, что общее число товаров в магазинах не изменилось.
С синхронизацией процесса перемещения товаров проблем нет. Но для проверки я не могу синхронизироваться по общей коллекции, потому что это остановит работу всех остальных потоков.
Но если этого не делать, пока проверяющий поток будет ходить по списку магазинов и суммировать число товаров, какой-то из потоков может переместить товар из непроверенного магазина в уже проверенный, и таким образом получится недостача. Как мне этого избежать?
Не прошу писать код, просто подайте, пожалуйста, какую-нибудь идею. Я пробовал использовать CopyOnWriteArrayList, но он не дает нужного результата, потому что я получаю копию листа, а сами объекты, которые лежат внутри него, в это время все равно могут изменяться. Даже если я буду заменять объекты в листе на новые, при перемещении товаров из магазина в магазин будет совершаться две операции (обновление числа товаров в одном магазине и в другом), и в каждом случае будет создаваться копия, и я могу взять промежуточную версию.

Comment: У задачи в такой постановке нет простого и элегантного решения. Есть варианты и у каждого свои минусы. Чтоб решить, на какие компромиссы вы готовы пойти и чем готовы заплатить (производительностью, сложностью кода и его поддержки) нужно понимать зачем вам эта проверка нужна. Это просто тестирование кода? Или это способ реализовать целостность операций? Или это бизнес-требование (что-то вроде регулярных(?) ревизий)?

Comment: Это бизнес-требование - регулярная ревизия общей коллекции одним потоком. Я уже готов пожертвовать чем угодно: и производительностью, и сложностью - просто, чтобы понять, как это реализовать, не останавливая перемещения на время проверки. Не могли бы вы направить меня, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Не может бизнес-требование звучать именно так "регулярная ревизия коллекции одним потоком". Пользователь не знает что такое поток, и что их может быть много и т.д. так как это деталь реализации. Это может быть ваше внутренне требование к реализации продиктованное каким-то другим бизнес-требованием. Как все-таки звучит бизнес-требование (оно должно быть выражено в терминах понятных пользователю приложения)?

Comment: "Я уже готов пожертвовать чем угодно: и производительностью ..., не останавливая перемещения на время проверки" - в том то и дело, что пожертвовать производительностью в данном случае означает остановить или ограничить перемещения. Поэтому, чтобы понять насколько это допустимо, нужно понять зачем пользователям это нужно. Какую пользовательскую задачу такая проверка будет решать.

Comment: Это задача, и требование звучит так: "Сделать поток-демон наблюдатель, обязанность которого - следить, что нет недостачи. Изначально задается общее число товаров во всех магазинах, с которым и нужно сравнивать результаты ревизии. Нельзя использовать для синхронизации общий глобальный объект, чтобы при проверке не останавливались другие потоки. Наблюдатель должен проверять кол-во товаров, актуально находящиеся в магазинах"

Comment: Простой и надежный способ, который я придумал: на время перемещения блокировать доступ к этим магазинам, и проверять не общую коллекцию, а именно перемещения (сравнивать сумму товаров в двух магазинах до и после перемещения). Но это не удовлетворяет условию задачи. А как сделать по-другому без синхронизации по коллекции ума не приложу.

Answer (score 1):

Идея с проверкой перемещений правильная и сработает. Нужно только реализовать ее так, чтоб не было блокировок потоков, которые совершают транзакции, т.е. которые перемещают данные.

Общая идея решения это создать журнал транзакций, в который каждая транзакция пишет изменение, которое она сделала. Поток-наблюдатель читает журнал операций и проверяет, что после каждой операции условие выполняется. Есть много нюансов как реализовать детали, я не буду во все вдаваться, но буду по ходу упоминать.

```
class Shop {
  Integer id;
  ...
}

class Transaction {
  // хранит для каждого идентификатора магазина изменение в количестве товара
  Map<Integer, Integer> changes;
}

ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Transaction> transactionLog = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

Теперь каждая транзакция должна добавлять в `transactionLog` изменение, которое она делает.

Чтобы избежать ошибок и злонамеренных действий, можно изменить API вашего хранилища магазинов так, чтоб к самим магазинам клиенты не имели доступа. А работали чисто с объектами транзакций, т.е. API хранилища будет не `List<Shop>` какой-нибудь, где можно достать любой магазин и сделать что угодно, а что-то вроде:

```
class Shops {
  private List<Shop> shops;

  // клиенты, которые хотят переместить что-то из магазина в магазин могут
  // делать это используя только этот метод 
  // список shops недоступен извне, а объекты Shop клиенты либо не могут достать вообще
  // либо они immutable, т.е. клиент не может изменять количество в обход process
  public void process(Transaction transaction) {
    // тут должна быть потокобезопасная обработка изменения
    // т.е. модификация значений в колекции shops используя данные из transaction
    ...
    
    transactionLog.add(transaction);
  }
}

Shops shops = ...
```

Тогда поток, который делает перемещение, будет выглядеть как-то так (тут я привожу вариант з неизменяемым(immutable) классом `Shop`):

```
// эта операция одновременно захватывает блокировку на запись к магазину
// чтоб никакой другой поток не мог параллельно его изменить
Shop shop1 = shops.getAndLock(SHOP_ID1);
Shop shop2 = shops.getAndLock(SHOP_ID2);
Map<Integer, Integer> moveTx = new HashMap<>();
moveTx.put(shop1.getId(), +20);
moveTx.put(shop2.getId(), -20);
shops.process(new Transaction(moveTx));
shops.releaseLock(shop2);
shops.releaseLock(shop1);
```

Поток-демон должен просто читать `transactionLog` и проверять, что после каждой транзакции у нас условие целостности выполняется.

Что касается блокировок/разблокировок отдельных магазинов в потоках. Пример, который я привел выше, демонстрирует, что должно происходить, само API конечно можно и нужно улучшить, чтобы не забыть разблокировать, например, и т.д.

Я имею ввиду что можно улучшить API класса Shops так:

```
  shops.update(asList(SHOP_ID1, SHOP_ID2), (Collection<Shop> shops, Transaction transaction) -> {
     transaction.add(SHOP_ID1, +20);
     transaction.add(SHOP_ID2, -20);
  });

  ...

  class Shops {
     
     interface TransactionCallback {
        void execute(Collection<Shop> shops, Transaction transaction);
     }
     
     void update(List<Integer> shopIds, TransactionCallback callback) {
       
       lockShops(shopIds);
       try {
          Transaction tx = new Transaction();
          List<Shop> shopsInTransaction = getShops(shopIds);
          callback.execute(shopsInTransaction, tx);
          process(tx); // теперь process будет private методом
       } finally {
         unlockShops(shopIds);
       } 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Но все же мы проверяем перемещения, а задача в том, чтобы проверять именно текущее состояние магазинов (с учетом тех, которые не участвовали в переводах).

Comment: Можно проверять и состояние. Придется все еще больше усложнить

Comment: Если знаете, как можно усложнить, подскажите, пожалуйста. Перепробовал уже много разных вариантов, но постоянно натыкаюсь или на дедлок, или на утечку.

Comment: Расписывать долго, как будет время - сделаю. Если в двух словах, то нужно реализовать MVCC смотрите https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-concurrency или https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-mvcc-multi-version-concurrency-control-work/ или https://kousiknath.medium.com/how-mvcc-databases-work-internally-84a27a380283